# Is it possible to merge Woocommerce attributes?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization

So I had someone add Woocommerce products for me, but the thing is he got the attributes wrong.
So basically the attributes are for colors, where I want to have Blue etc. but it's been added like Dark Blue, Rich Blue, Light Blue etc. I want all attributes of the color blue to be under the attribute blue not one for every shade of blue.

So my question is if it's possible to merge Woocommerce attributes?

Comment: yes possible... Your questions quality is poor. Try to improve it.